# I have an array of numbers. the issue is to get an array of unique objects from this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Need to assign them to object as values of `'value'` and `'title'` keys several times and push each of those objects into an array. Trying to do something like this:

```js
const myArr = [1, 2, 3];
const newArr: {value: string, title: string}[] = []
const newObj = {}

myArr.forEach(item => {
   Object.assign(newObj, {value: item.toString(), title: item.toString()});
   newArr.push(newObj);
}
```

But the output is:

```js
[
   {
      value: 3,
      title: 3
   },
   {
      value: 3,
      title: 3
   },
   {
      value: 3,
      title: 3
   }
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You need to move `newObj` inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use assign, you can push objects directly:

```
const myArr = [1, 2, 3];
const newArr: {value: string, title: string}[] = []

myArr.forEach(item => {
  newArr.push({value: item.toString(), title: item.toString()});
})

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `newObj` entity is the same throughout. SO when you are doing `.assign(` you are only making changes to the existing `newObj`.

In the end you have three array elements all pointing to `newObj`. They will have the same key values.

Create your obj inside the loop, so it is unique every time.

```
const myArr = [1, 2, 3];
const newArr: {value: string, title: string}[] = []

myArr.forEach(item => {
  const newObj = {}
  Object.assign(newObj, {value: item.toString(), title: item.toString()});
  newArr.push(newObj);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing the same object so you are just pushing the same object into the array. So when you are updating the properties of the object, you are updating each thing.

```
const myArr = [1, 2, 3];
const newArr: {value: string, title: string}[] = []

myArr.forEach(item => {
  const newObj = {}
  Object.assign(newObj, {value: item.toString(), title: item.toString()});
  newArr.push(newObj);
}
```

But unless you are setting defaults there is no real reason to use Object assign

```
const myArr = [1, 2, 3];
const newArr: {value: string, title: string}[] = []

myArr.forEach(item => {
  newArr.push({value: item.toString(), title: item.toString()});
}
```

Or just use map

```
const myArr = [1, 2, 3];
const newArr: {value: string, title: string}[] = myArr.map(item => ({value: item.toString(), title: item.toString()}));
```